# Rails nginx + passenger and new rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Hello i have nginx with passenger, i setup vhost and run

```
rvmsudo rails new
rvmsudo rails g scaffold user name:string surname:string
rvmsudo rake db:create
rvmsudo rake db:migrate
```

(all fine)

when i look on browser, im getting welcome page.. ok cool but if i click on 
`About your application’s environment` im getting `404 Not Found`
in error.log i have 
`open() "/var/www/default/public/rails/info/properties" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

and servername.tld/users doesnt work too :-( whats problem here ? thank you

edit:
nginx.conf

```
http {
    passenger_root /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/gems/passenger-4.0.14;
    passenger_ruby /home/lukas/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/ruby;
...
```

vhost

```
server {
 listen *:80;
 server_name hostname.org www.hostname.org

 passenger_enabled on;
 rails_env production;
 root /var/www/default/public;

 error_log /opt/nginx/logs/vhosts/default/error.log;
 access_log /opt/nginx/logs/vhosts/default/access.log combined;
}
```

if i run `rvmsudo rails s` on port 3000 everything work but i want to use nginx.

Comment: Rails welcome page is static page located at public/index.html. Nginx with default settings could serve static pages, but accessing to results of Rails' rendered pages require nginx.conf editing.

Comment: i know i edited question

Answer (score 0):

missing `;` at server_name directive.. ohmy :-)